# How to get the number of lines of a csv file on S3 without downloading?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

We are doing files uploaded to Amazon S3, and I would like to add a feature to show the number of rows in a file. How to get the number of lines of a csv file on S3 without downloading?

Comment: Without accessing the content of the file? Difficult... Without downloading, you would need some logic on the server side.

Comment: One possible solution is to add it to file metadata when uploading file to S3.

Answer (score 6):

There is a feature called [Amazon S3 Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectSELECTContent.html) that can run queries across CSV files.

You could use it to simply count the number of lines (`SELECT COUNT(*)`) without having to download the object.